# Scalaz instancing typeclass and case class

Tags: scala, class, oop, functional-programming, scalaz

This problem is pretty hard to explain. I try to implement a kind of `Arrow`, call it `MyArr`, which extends the `Arrow` trait from `scalaz`. However, `MyArr` is also a kind of Algbraic Data Type, so I make a few case classes out of if, and wrote down code like this(minimal example):

```
package org.timeless

import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import std.option._, std.list._

sealed trait MyArr[A,B] extends Arrow[MyArr] {
  def id[A]: MyArr[A,A] = SId()
  def compose[A,B,C](s1: MyArr[B,C], s2: MyArr[A,B]): MyArr[A,C] =
    SRight(s2, s1)
  def arr[A,B](f: A=>B): MyArr[A,B] = SPure(f)
  def first[A,B,C](s: MyArr[A,B]): MyArr[(A,C),(B,C)] = SPar(s, SId())
}

case class SId[A] () extends MyArr[A,A]()
case class SRight[M[_],A,B,C](s1: MyArr[A,B], s2: MyArr[B,C]) extends MyArr[A,C]
case class SPure[A,B](f: A=>B) extends MyArr[A,B]
case class SPar[M[_],A,B,C,D](s1: MyArr[A,B], s2: MyArr[C,D]) extends MyArr[(A,C),(B,D)]

object MyArr {
  val b = SId[Int]()
  val c = SId[Int]()
  // val a: MyArr[Int,Int] = id[Int] // Error
  // val d = c compose b // Error
  // val d = b >>> c // Error
  val d = b >>> (b,c) // ??? Arguments
}
```

As easily seen, the `id` function is actually the constructor of `SId`, etc. The classes themselves compile fine, but I don't see any way to actually use it as an `Arrow`. I actually came from Haskell programming, so I might be doing it totally wrong, but equivalent code in Haskell should be like this(with GADTs):

```
data MyArr a b where
  SId :: MyArr a b
  SRight :: MyArr a b -> MyArr b c -> MyArr a c
  SPure :: (a -> b) -> MyArr a b
  SPar :: MyArr a b -> MyArr c d -> MyArr (a,c) (b,d)

instance Category MyArr where
  id = SId
  (.) = SRight

instance Arrow MyArr where
  arr = SPure
  first s = SPar s SId
```

Answer (score 2):

### Typeclasses in Scala

Typeclasses in Scala are not built into the language like in Haskell. They are just a design pattern and are usually implemented with the help of implicit arguments:

```
def pure[M[_], T](
  implicit monad: Monad[M] // Fetching a monad instance for type M
): M[T] = 
  monad.pure[T]            // Using methods of the monad instance
```

You don't have to extend the typeclass trait to provide a typeclass instance for some ADT. The typeclass instance has to be defined somewhere as an `implicit val`, `implicit def`, `implicit object`, etc. Then you can `import` the relevant instance into scope before using it.

There is also a way to supply the typeclass instance automatically, without having to import it explicitly. To do that the instance should be declared in the companion object of either the typeclass class/trait or ADT class/trait, or one of their parent classes/traits; or in a package object in which one of those is defined. You can read more on the topic of implicit resolution in this answer: [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598107/1098230)

### Defining a typeclass instance

So to get back to your problem, you can define your ADT like this:

```
sealed trait MyArr[A,B]
case class SId[A] () extends MyArr[A,A]()
case class SRight[M[_],A,B,C](s1: MyArr[A,B], s2: MyArr[B,C]) extends MyArr[A,C]
case class SPure[A,B](f: A=>B) extends MyArr[A,B]
case class SPar[M[_],A,B,C,D](s1: MyArr[A,B], s2: MyArr[C,D]) extends MyArr[(A,C),(B,D)]
```

And provide the `Arrow` instance in the companion object of `MyArr`:

```
object MyArr {
  implicit val arrow: Arrow[MyArr] = new Arrow[MyArr] {
    def id[A]: MyArr[A,A] = SId()
    def compose[A,B,C](s1: MyArr[B,C], s2: MyArr[A,B]): MyArr[A,C] =
    SRight(s2, s1)
    def arr[A,B](f: A=>B): MyArr[A,B] = SPure(f)
    def first[A,B,C](s: MyArr[A,B]): MyArr[(A,C),(B,C)] = SPar(s, SId())
  }

  def apply[T]: MyArr[T, T] = arrow.id[T]
}
```

### Using the typeclass instance

I believe it's not possible to provide a generic `id` function (or `return`, `pure`, etc.) in Scala due to some limitations of Scala's type inference.

Instead you can use the `MyArr.apply` method defined above:

```
val a: MyArr[Int,Int] = MyArr[Int]
```

As the ADT doesn't extend the typeclass, it doesn't inherit its methods like `compose` or `>>>`. They can be provided separately using the ['Pimp My Library' pattern](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-2.10-implicit-class-example).

Indeed, the `>>>` method in scalaz comes from the `ComposeOps` class, which is defined like this:

```
final class ComposeOps[F[_, _],A, B] private[syntax]
  (self: F[A, B])
  (val F: Compose[F]) 
  extends Ops[F[A, B]]
```

And there is an implicit conversion defined from some type `F[_, _]` to this class `ComposeOps`, if there as a `Compose` instance available for `F`:

```
implicit def ToComposeOps[F[_, _],A, B](v: F[A, B])(implicit F0: Compose[F])
```

This conversion is imported with `import Scalaz._`, and that's why this line works now:

```
val d = b >>> c
```

But there is no extension in scalaz that provides a `compose` method on ADTs with an `Arrow` instance, so this line still gives an error:

```
val e = c compose b
```

To make it work, you can provide an extension yourself. A simple example could look like this:

```
// implicit class is equivalent to a normal class 
// with an implicit conversion to this class
implicit class ArrowOps[T[_, _], A, B](f: T[A, B])(implicit arrow: Arrow[T]) {
  def compose[C](g: T[C, A]): T[C, B] = arrow.compose(f, g)
}
```

Comment: Now, what if I change `MyArr` to `MyArr[M,A,B]` to have the arrow work under a monad? I tried to write a type lambda, but stuck at type definition: `implicit val arrow: Arrow[???] = new Arrow[???]`.

Comment: @CarlDong The straightforward definition of the instance using type lambdas would look like this: `implicit def arrow[M[_]]: Arrow[({type T[A, B] = MyArr[M, A, B]})#T] = new Arrow[({type T[A, B] = MyArr[M, A, B]})#T] { /* ... */ }`. You would also need a special definition of `ArrowOps` for that case. Look at how `ToComposeOps` in Scalaz is defined with 2 methods `ToComposeOps` and `ToComposeVFromKleisliLike`.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't look like I can use `first` or `arr` either... I'll do some more testing to see if this works as intended

Comment: @CarlDong I think you can use `first` normally, but you usually have to specify the type of the second argument explicitly (e.g. `b.first[String]`), because it's usually impossible to typecheck it otherwise in Scala's type system. Also, this `first` is defined in `Strong` typeclass (extended by `Arrow`)/`StrongOps` extension class.

Comment: @CarlDong As for `arr`, I think it's not possible to have a generic thing like this (the same as for `id`, `pure`, `return`, etc.). But you can, for example, define another `apply` method in `object MyArr`: `def apply[A, B](f: A => B): MyArr[A, B] = arrow.arr(f)`